# I want to create another user table in laravel with auth

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication

I'm using Laravel's user table for admin login and registration. I want to create another user table for app user with authentication.

How do I go about it?

Comment: If you didn't yet, start by reading Laravel's guide about authentication, you have everything you need within it. If you still don't succeed, then come here and we'll help you. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

Comment: Are you able to explain why you want to create a new table rather than using the existing one? I only ask because there might be a better way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: You should create custom `auth` for solve your problem